# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 with static library

Tags: ios, architecture, quickblox, armv7

I've been trawling around the internet for around 3 hours and still haven't managed to find a fix. I've tried adding the library 'QuickBlox' and the needed frameworks and links in Frameworks Search Paths - but still continue to get errors. Although it's asked for libresolv.dylb, which isn't available in iOS 9. I get a large amount of errors which are reasonably similar like the one below:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_xmlCreatePushParserCtxt", referenced from:
      l002 in Quickblox(XMPPParser.o)
  "_xmlFree", referenced from:
      l024 in Quickblox(DDXMLNode.o)
      l025 in Quickblox(DDXMLNode.o)
      l075 in Quickblox(DDXMLNode.o)
      l077 in Quickblox(DDXMLNode.o)
      l105 in Quickblox(DDXMLNode.o)
      l003 in Quickblox(XMPPParser.o)
```

I'm wandering what the main issue is - I feel as though everything should be working!

Cheers - SebOH.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's a bug with in the Xcode 7 Beta. Upgrading to Beta 3 - hopefully will fix issues.

[LINK](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4572)